# Why do Umlauts and special characters not show up correctly in my Grails pages?

Tags: grails, groovy, content-encoding

How do I make sure the correct encoding (UTF-8) is used by Grails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier than I thought - simply make sure your editor is set to UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shouldn't use UTF-8. Maybe you should try one of the 8859 ISO charsets:http://www.global-translation-services.com/iso8859.html#ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 0):

I've found that sometimes setting the file type to UTF-8 isn't enough.  Sometimes you need to tell the AppServer.

`response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`